# How to add MinGW to PATH?

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm following [this tutorial by vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) to install a C++ compiler on Windows. Right now, I'm trying to edit C:\msys64\mingw64\bin to environment variables and save MinGW to path. I clicked OK multiple times but seems like it can't save. I also entered g++ --version and gdb --version to check for installation. It just shows "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Did you restart VSC and/or the terminal after modifying PATH?

Comment: You mean restarting the computer?

Comment: No. By terminal I mean the console - if that's where you're typing `g++ --version`.

Comment: Yes I did restart

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling `MinGW` doesn't work, add `MinGW` to `PATH` manually by this:

1. Find your `computer's property`, and then go to `Advanced`.
2. Click `Alt+N`
3. Find `PATH` in the box below.
4. Add the path of your `MinGW compiler` to it.
   Note: Add the **`BIN folder`**.

If adding the `BIN folder` doesn't work, add the `BIN folder` in the folder under `C:\msys64\mingw64` that has a long name like this:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

or whatever your folder is named.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: REMEMBER TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER AFTER DOING THIS.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried setx PATH “%PATH%; C:\msys64\mingw64\bin in cmd, if it doesn’t work I’ll check out this solution.